# The converse of Lagrange mean value theorem

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ be a continuous function in the interval $[a,b]$ and differentiable in $(a,b)$.

Is it possible, for each $x \in (a,b)$ to find $a_x \in (a,b)$ and $b_x \in (a,b)$ so that $f'(x) = \frac{f(b_x)-f(a_x)}{b_x-a_x}$?

Comment: Consider $f(x)=x^3$ on $[-1,1]$ with $x=0$.

Comment: @DavidMitra Do you know what the best possible result is? Can we find $a_x,b_x$ for almost every $x$?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo No to your first question. But, I'll give it some thought.

Comment: J.M. Borwein and Xianfu Wang, *The converse of the mean value theorem may fail generically*, Amer. Math Mothly 105 (1998), 847-848 gives an example where the set of "bad points" are dense (but of measure $0$). [This](http://www.jstor.org/discover/2974475?sid=21104912189061&uid=2&uid=3739896&uid=4&uid=70&uid=3739256&uid=2129) paper shows that a point $x$ is "good" if $f'(x)$ is a global extreme value.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo The results of [this paper](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDkQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hcm.uni-bonn.de%2Ffileadmin%2Fgeschke%2Fpapers%2FManyLocalMins3.pdf&ei=3vuWVOymBoq1ggT8rIPQDw&usg=AFQjCNFtxzNcVT9l2maRWG9tPSDnNbF0lw&bvm=bv.82001339,d.eXY)  lead me to surmise  there may be hope that one can have a set of "bad  points" of positive measure.

Comment: @DavidMitra Thank you. There are quite a few interesting papers on the topic! (And Stefan's note was nice.)